# Rounding a number in SQL Oracle by just matching up to first two decimal values

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I am trying to group things together based on rounding the price together if the up to the 2nd decimal place is a direct match. So 16.49 should group with 16.4991, and the quantity (which will always match up perfectly). It will not always work to round up or down. Is round not the best way to approach something like this? If someone could point me in a better direction.

```
PRICE   QUANTITY
16.49   1460
16.4991 1460
15.63   38638
15.6352 38638
```

Comment: Should 15.63 and 15.6352 be combined?  What if there were a 15.6314?

Comment: `16.4991` rounded to two decimals would yield `16.50` not `16.49` - this sounds as if you want to simply remove the decimals after the second. In Postgres you could use `trunc(16.4991, 2)` for that.

Comment: Yes those two should be combined. So anything that is 15.63xxxxxxx should be combined with 15.63

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ignore my previous comment; your comment came as I posted.

Comment: You can try [`TRUNCATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate). Your solution will depend partly on your database system and partly the business logic you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am using Oracle

Comment: SELECT TRUNC(16.4991 * 100) / 100 AS PRICE FROM dual

Answer (score 1):

Use `trunc` rather than round as @a_horse_with_no_name suggested in comments

```
with tbl as (
  select 16.49 price,   1460 quantity from dual union all
  select 16.4991, 1460 from dual union all
  select 15.63,   38638 from dual union all
  select 15.6352, 38638 from dual
 )
 select trunc(price, 2), quantity, count(*)
   from tbl
  group by trunc(price, 2), quantity
```